# jQuery for loop for element ID

Tags: jquery, for-loop

I have total six rows fields containing column from 1 to 3 for example #prefix_row1_content_col1 has 3 column

`row1_col1_, row1_col2_, row1_colr3_` but other can have 2 or 1 or 3

Now I am trying to hide form fields based on dropdown select value and it is working fine if I add all ID manually but is there anyway (without adding class) where I don't have to write code for every row?

For instance using nested for loop for row and col? Here is my code

```
$('#' + prefix + 'row1_content_col1').change(function() {

    $('#' + prefix + 'row1_col1_youtube, #' + prefix + 'row1_col1_rss_feed_url, #' + prefix + 'row1_col1_custom_php, #' + prefix + 'row1_col1_advert').fadeOut();

    $('#' + prefix + 'row1_col1_' + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
    $('#' + prefix + 'row1_col1_' + $(this).val() + '_url').fadeIn();


}).change();
```

I have tried for loop but didn't work may be I have done something wrong, as I am not so familiar with jQuery

```
for(c=1; c<=6; c++){
    $('#' + prefix + 'row1_content_col'+c).change(function() {

        $('#' + prefix + 'row1_col'+c+'_youtube, #' + prefix + 'row1_col'+c+'_rss_feed_url, #' + prefix + 'row1_col'+c+'_custom_php, #' + prefix + 'row1_col'+c+'_advert').fadeOut();

        $('#' + prefix + 'row1_col'+c+'_' + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
        $('#' + prefix + 'row1_col'+c+'_' + $(this).val() + '_url').fadeIn();


    }).change();
}
```

HTML Markup

```
<select id="fp_row1_content_col1" name="fp_row1_content_col1">
    <option value="youtube">youtube</option>
    <option value="rss_feed">rss_feed</option>
    <option value="custom_php">custom_php</option>
    <option value="advert">advert</option>
</select>

<div id="fp_row1_col1_heading">
    <input type="text" value="" name="fp_row1_col1_youtube">
</div>

<div id="fp_row1_col1_rss_feed_url">
    <input type="text" class="qa-form-tall-text" value="" name="fp_row1_col1_rss_feed_url">
</div>

..........

<select id="fp_row1_content_col3" name="fp_row1_content_col3">
    <option value="youtube">youtube</option>
    <option value="rss_feed">rss_feed</option>
    <option value="custom_php">custom_php</option>
    <option value="advert">advert</option>
</select>

<div id="fp_row1_col3_heading">
    <input type="text" value="Youtube Video" name="fp_row1_col3_heading">
</div>

<div id="fp_row1_col3_rss_feed_url">
    <input type="text" class="qa-form-tall-text" value="" name="fp_row1_col3_rss_feed_url">
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use class?

Comment: Fields generate by array keys and that doesn't allows to add class on the section which I want to show/hide

Comment: Could you show html code?

Comment: @twil I have updated my question with markup

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select elements by id [starting or containing something](http://api.jquery.com/?s=selector). Eg.

```
$('[id^="' + prefix + 'row1_col"]')
```

### Update

Based on HTML you provided try this

```
// global list
fields = [
    'youtube',
    'rss_feed_url',
    'custom',
    'social',
    'advert'
];


// inside <select> change event handler

// get row num
var row_num = this.id.replace(prefix, '').split('_')[0]; // returns 'rowN'

// get all row fields
var row_fields = $('[id^="' + prefix + row_num + '"]');
// hide all row fields
for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
    row_fields.filter('[id$="' + fields[i] + '"]').fadeOut();

// show selected (with rss_feed corner case)
row_fields.filter('[id$="' + $(this).val() + '"]').fadeIn();
row_fields.filter('[id$="' + $(this).val() + '_url"]').fadeIn();
```

Comment: I have total 5 fields containing words in them ids `youtube`, `rss_feed`, `custom`, `social`, `advert` now this value I am getting from dropdown selection. So how can I use those words in your code getting by select option value?

Comment: Do you have ID on your select fields? What it looks like?

Comment: Yes I have ID on select field as well as elements what I want to hide and how. Elements containing the word of select option in the ID. For instance if option is youtube than element id is like `row1_col1_youtube_video_id` something like for all other elements

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating new functions in the for loop, the variable `c` lives afterwards in those created functions, but has the value `7` in all of them.  A better way would be to modify the control's id slightly:

```
// remove the content part to make it easier to find the other elements
'#' + prefix + 'row1_col'+c
```

and use that to refer to the other, related elements:

```
for(c=1; c<=6; c++){
    $('#' + prefix + 'row1_col'+c).change(function() {
        $('#' + this.id + '_youtube, #' + this.id +'_rss_feed_url, #' + this.id +'_custom_php, #' + this.id + '_advert').fadeOut();

        $('#' + this.id + '_' + this.value).fadeIn();
        $('#' + this.id + '_' + this.value + '_url').fadeIn();

    }).change();
}
```

Comment: bit confused! :( you mean to replace `'#' + prefix + 'row1_col'+c` with `'#' + this.id + ` ? if that is what you are asking than but my element id containing the word of that defined id. I mean `_youtube`, `_rss_feed_url` etc..

Comment: Updated with some more context, maybe that helps?

Comment: Thanks for the code but you changed select ID and if I am changing it is not working on my code..believe there are many id's similar to row1_col1 causing the issue

Comment: You are using `heading` instead of `youtube` - make sure your HTML is actually correct

Comment: Ah! my bad.. I just pasted heading field's code. I will update it